# iptables not working on mobile broadband

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, vpn

I access the internet using a VPN. With the help of iptables rules all out-going traffic from my machine to the internet is dropped instantly when my VPN connection is abruptly terminated.

The iptables rules work on a wired connection but they do not when I am using mobile broadband. The said rules are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please wait a moment......"
echo "Save original iptables. Apply new iptables rules"

iptables-save > /home/username/vpn/iptables.save

iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack -j DROP --ctstate INVALID
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -s 123.123.123.123 -i eth0 --sport 443 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED #example.conf
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -d 123.123.123.123 -o eth0 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED #example.conf
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -s 123.123.123.123 -i usb0 --sport 443 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED #example.conf
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -d 123.123.123.123 -o usb0 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED #example.conf
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j REJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -o tun0 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -o tun0 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -o tun0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -o tun0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -i tun0 --sport 80 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -i tun0 --sport 443 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -i tun0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -i tun0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

I tried to solve the problem by sudo-ing and editing the file */etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules* to include the following line:

```
# Mobile Broadband USB dongle
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="MAC address of dongle", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="usb0"
```

If it is helpful to you, below is the contents of the file *70-persistent-net.rules*

```
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device (r8169)
#SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="MAC address of ethernet card", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# Mobile Broadband USB dongle
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="MAC address of dongle", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="usb0"
```

**Additional details**

To get mobile broadband to work on Debian 7.9, I carried out the following steps:

(1) Add the following line to */lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules*

```
# Mobile Broadband USB dongle
ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0257", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

(2) Create a file called **19d2:0257** in */etc/usb_modeswitch.d/* with the following contents:

```
# Mobile Broadband USB dongle
#
DefaultVendor= 0x19d2
DefaultProduct= 0x0257
TargetVendor= 0x19d2
TargetProduct= 0x0257
MessageContent="55534243123456782400000080000685000000240000000000000000000000"
CheckSuccess=20
```

(3 In order for Network Manager to recognize the device automatically, I add the following line to */etc/rc.local*

```
modprobe usbserial vendor=0x19d2 product=0x0257
```

Comment: In what way are the rules not working? What *are* the rules? What is your routing table?

Comment: @Gilles: `In what way are the rules not working?` When my connection to the VPN is abruptly terminated, the iptables rules should kick in, preventing my machine from accessing the internet or traffic going out from my machine to the internet. However they fail to work when I am using mobile broadband. (They work fine when I am on a wired connection, such as eth0)

Comment: @Gilles: `What are the rules?` I have amended my original post to include the iptables rules. Please have a re-look at my original post.

Comment: Voted to reopen. I haven't looked in detail, but you have a bunch of rules for `eth0`. Shouldn't you have the same rules for `usb0`?